# How to use gradlew command for jhipster project using openApiGenerator

Tags: jhipster, openapi-generator

I created my application using Jhipster with open apiGenerator and I am unable to execute gradlew command.

Things I did

1)I read in the docs about open api generate but I cannot find it useful to remove the error.
2)I also cannot get much help from the other SO answers and google
Below is the link for my project

https://github.com/trustjalaj/DockerDemo

and the link of the output I got after using command ./gradlew

https://scans.gradle.com/s/dbf3ed7aqoha6/

> Can any experienced person guide me on how to run gradlew command successfully.

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a title to your `api.yml` found in `src/main/resources/swagger`.  This will allow your project to compile.

This will be fixed in the generator [by this pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/8387).